# При импортировании модуля math количество ссылок на объект None уменьшается

Tags: python, python-3.x

Заметил интересное поведение, понять которое не могу.

При импортировании модуля `math` кол-во ссылок на объект `None` уменьшается:

```py
import sys

print(sys.getrefcount(None))
import math
print(sys.getrefcount(None))
```

Вывод:

```
4138
4099
```

Стало интересно, почему так происходит. Если кто объяснит буду рад)

Comment: Я создам иссуе на github, самому интересно.

Comment: Создал: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/108199.

Comment: А вот что выводит `Google Colab`: `46208 46222`, а если ещё позапускать, то `46267 46267`. Короче, это вопрос реализации конкретной версии конкретного интерпретатора питона.

Comment: math не единственный модуль,который вызывает такое поведение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как [сказали](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/108199#issuecomment-1687213199) проффесионалы:

> I think this is just [the method cache filling up in Python 3.8](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1663f8ba8405fefc82f74f8d1ed86d6f26250658/Objects/typeobject.c#L3160). When a cache entry gets filled, it drops a reference to None and instead holds a reference to a string.
>
> A little printf-debugging showed this:
>
> ```
> >>> import math
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\listobject.c:2488
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\listobject.c:2488
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\compile.c:1331
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\compile.c:1331
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2373
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:6805
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2978
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2373
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:6805
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:3390
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:3391
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2978
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2978
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2373
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2373
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2373
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\frameobject.c:430
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:6805
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\frameobject.c:430
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\frameobject.c:430
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:4971
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:4971
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\frameobject.c:430
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\frameobject.c:430
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\frameobject.c:430
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:3390
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:3391
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\frameobject.c:430
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\frameobject.c:430
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:4971
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\typeobject.c:3160
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:4971
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:4971
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2978
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:4971
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2978
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2978
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:4971
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2978
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2978
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2979
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\frameobject.c:430
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2373
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:3390
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:3391
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:1363
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\weakrefobject.c:939
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Objects\funcobject.c:585
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:3390
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:3391
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\ceval.c:2995
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Include\object.h:560
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\pythonrun.c:268
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Modules\_io\bufferedio.c:804
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\pythonrun.c:1126
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Modules\_io\bufferedio.c:804
> INCREF None
> DECREF None at C:\Users\sween\Source\Repos\cpython2\cpython\Python\pythonrun.c:1134
> ```

Перевод:

> Я думаю, что это просто [заполнения кэша методов в Python 3.8](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1663f8ba8405fefc82f74f8d1ed86d6f26250658/Objects/typeobject.c#L3160). Когда запись кэша заполняется, она удаляет ссылку на None и вместо этого содержит ссылку на строку.
>
> Небольшой отладочный printf показал это:
>
> -- обрезано --

То есть дело в том что math не хватает кэша методов (method cache) и он удаляет оттуда лишние None.

Comment: В общем, это какие-то детали реализации, ничему нас в общем не учащие )

Comment: @CrazyElf а чему они нас могли бы учить?

Comment: О каком конкретно кеше идет речь?

Comment: @чистов_n Каким-то приёмам или принципам, которые могли бы нам пригодиться в дальнейшем. А тут просто какой-то забавный факт. Хотя кое-что интересное всё-равно есть.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy изменил ответ, добавил ссылку которая была в комментарии но у меня её не было (the method cache filling up in Python 3.8)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а ещё иcправил перевод.

Answer (score 3):

я конечно не знаток, но мне кажется что для `math` надо много памяти, а `None` самый ненужный оператор. попробуй создать функцию, после импорта `math`, и ссылки опять уменьшатся.

```py
import sys

print(sys.getrefcount(None))
import math
print(sys.getrefcount(None))
def no():
    pass
print(sys.getrefcount(None))
```

Comment: Такая версия имеет место быть, но возникают вопросы. Что такое "самый ненужный оператор", как работает внутри питона определение ненужности и устранение ненужных ссылок? А так-же интересно увидеть не только гипотезу, но и ее подтверждение.

Comment: ну, просто `None` можно заменить любым другим символом, обьектом и тд. я лично его использовал только 3 раза за все 4 года уверенного программирования.

Comment: @ГеоргийМартиросов, зря. Оператор None очень полезная штука.

Comment: кому как) лично я его не использую

Comment: @ГеоргийМартиросов А как тогда вы пишете функции с дефолтными параметрами-коллекциями, например? )

Comment: @CrazyElf ну вот видимо он это делал только 3 раза :)

Comment: я им просто сразу даю параметры нужные.

Comment: @чистов_n а что я делал 3 раза?

Comment: @ГеоргийМартиросов, функции с дефолтными параметрами-коллекциями.